# FB registration form not showing to anyone else except me

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, zend-framework2, facebook-php-sdk

I Have a strange issue i integrated Fb Register/Login with my site but strangest thing is it shows me registeration form with all my info pulled from FB when i accept to provide info on facebook but to everyone else it does not show registeration form just logs them in

Very Strange!

Please hav look at snapshot

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Btw., that plugin has been removed with API v2.0, and will stop working on July 30, 2015: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.1

Comment: Yep but seems working now

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like you haven't made your application for this facebook login public.

1. go to the [facebook developers site](https://developers.facebook.com)
2. select your application for this login form from the top menu "Apps"
3. go to **"Status & Review"**
4. check that "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" is "**YES**"